# Convert HTML site to WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am totally a beginner to WordPress. I have a html site that needs to be converted to WordPress. And it should be fully customizable. I have seen plenty of tutorials but those didn't help. Anyone who can help?

Comment: The best wordpress to website convertor out their is on http://wpsiteconvertor.com/. It will be fully customizable and you'll be able to convert it in a couple of minutes without any wordpress coding knowledge. You do need to know a bit of html though.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great question for SO but FYI you need to consider what your site contains. Is it a bunch of HTML pages each of which represents a page with content or a post with content?

Wordpress is a CMS (content management system). It primarily deals with posts (dated items), pages (static posts), and images (media). Think about how your content in your existing HTML site will map to Wordpress.

Finally think about the rationale to move. There is a trend to move away from CMS / Wordpress to static HTML sites (for performance and security). What would you win out of migrating?

You see, more questions than answers. Keep investigating and come back with specific questions.

Comment: It's a shopping site. I have knowledge of HTML CSS but never worked on WordPress. The site was given to be by a person who wants it to be customizable at first I thought I could do it, but this seems very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

1. Use some online converter, like https://htmltowordpress.io/ ( but I guess you'll have do some tweaks after to suite your needs)
2. Install clean WordPress on your host and search for some good WordPress theme, that could be tweaked to look like yours original site Front End.
3. Hire a freelancer do do the work for you, It should't be very expensive :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You should have a good knowledge of html,php and css.
You can choose to start with one these two of following options.

1, Creating a new theme.

2, Choosing an exixting theme and updating it.

You can find both the above given options at https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites

Hope this will help.